# Latex: Ghostscript call for EPS to PDF conversion failing

Tags: eps, ghostscript, xdvipdfmx

I am using eps graph for my work. Latex version is TeXstudio 2.12.10, Miktex 2.9. Code to include graph

```
\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics*[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio=false]{Graph1a.eps}  
    \caption{$T_d$ under various $V_m$ }
\end{subfigure}
```

I have included `\usepackage{epstopdf}` but still, it gives me the error

> MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.19: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
>       xdvipdfmx:fatal: pdf_ref_obj(): passed invalid object. Output file removed.

Any, help is appreciated.

Comment: can you provide the image `Graph1a.eps` for a test?

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem whle compiling this file, called `test.tex`, under MiKTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics*[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio=false]{FIG1.eps}  
\end{document}
```

Note, however, that, as stated at the [`epstodpf` package dosumentation](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/epstopdf.pdf), the command line should be:

`pdflatex --enable-write18 test.tex`

Comment: `shell-escape` is not needed! `epstopdf` is one of the allowed external programs

Comment: actually it's `repstopdf`, a restricted version of `epstopdf` that's allowed. Also, use the `graphicx` package rather than the `epstopdf` package.